# When using ar command, library not being created

Tags: c, makefile, static-libraries, exe

When trying to create a static library from a makefile, the library does not get created. Anyone have any input on this?

```
all: test.exe

test.exe: test.o
    gcc -o test.exe test.o -L. -ltest

test.o: libtest.a
    gcc -c test.c

libtest.a: ABC-test.o
    ar rcs ABC-test.o

ABC-test.o: A-test.c B-test.c C-test.c
    gcc -c A-test.c B-test.c C-test.c
```

Comment: Does `test.o` already exist from a previous compilation?  If it does there is no reason for Make to create libtest.a.  test.exe should probably require lib test.a as well.

Comment: It won't exist from a previous compilation.

Comment: Do you get any errors during the compilation? Your rule for `ABC-test.o` looks wrong as it does not actually result in `ABC-test.o` being built. If that is not it, then please show the build log.

Comment: It would if you had compiled by hand at some point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this rule:

```
libtest.a: ABC-test.o
    ar rcs ABC-test.o
```

you forgot to pass the name of the library to `ar`. Try this:

```
libtest.a: ABC-test.o
    ar rcs libtest.a ABC-test.o
```

or better:

```
libtest.a: ABC-test.o
    ar rcs $@ $^
```

Comment: There's also the built-in rule: `ARFLAGS := rcs` `libtest.a: libtest.a(ABC-test.o)`